# How to confine the width of a container to the width of its flexible element

Tags: css

A div tag contains an image and a caption. The image size responds to the height of the viewport. How can the width of the caption be confined to the width of the flexible image?

```css
.container {
    display: inline-block; 
    background-color: yellow;
}
img {
    height: 80vh;
}
.caption {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.png">
    <div class="caption">
        The width of the caption should not exceed the width of the image.
    </div>
</div>
```